# Data manipulation logic !! should be as a part of fetch via DB link or an independent routine

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

The question may not be sufficient to give an insight.

I have two DB instances : A and B on the same server.
B reads data from several tables in A(A1,A2,A3...) via DB link and maintains  history of data in the replicated tables(A1_ext, A2_ext, A3_ext, as they have additional columns assume its status column) , i.e if its identified that a new row has been added in A1 ,a row is created in A1_ext with some status called as VALID , if a row is updated in A1, the existing data in A1_ext is updated to INVALID and a new row having latest data from A1 is created in A1_ext with status VALID.

For now the implemenetd logic is : Read data from A1 via db link , check if its exists in A1_ext , if does, delimit the existing one and create a new one.

Is it an efficient approach??

Or should it be like read all updated data from A1 and pull them at one go(bulk collect say) on B instance in A1_stag table(new). Then run the logic of update/insert on A1_ext.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is something like the following:

```
-- Insert the new and changed records with status NEW
insert into A1_ext
with upsert as (
  select id, val from A1@RemoteDB
  minus
  select id, val from A1_ext where status = 'VALID'
) select id, val, 'NEW' from upsert;

-- Update the old VALID records that have NEW records to INVALID
update A1_ext old 
   set status = 'INVALID'
 where status = 'VALID'
   and exists (select 1 from A1_ext new
                where new.id = old.id
                  and new.status = 'NEW');

-- Update all NEW records to VALID
update A1_ext set status = 'VALID' where status = 'NEW';
```

Unfortunately the first query is going to do a full table scan on A1@RemoteDB and transmit all that data across the database link.  Possibly not a big deal when both DBs reside on the same server, but possibly a performance problem for large tables across a network.  The minus operation will prune away the unchanged records after they've crossed the link but before they get into the *_EXT table.  If you can reliably filter the source data to just the new and updated records that would help limit the amount of data crossing the DB link.

The 2nd and 3rd queries are just house keeping to mark updated records as invalid and to mark the new data as valid.

If possible keep this as pure SQL and avoid context switching between SQL and PL/SQL as much as possible.